# Typescript definition for a stateful React.Component in an interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the correct typing to define for a property that is assigned to a stateful `React.Component` inside an interface.

The `TemplateConfiguration` interface has two properties `Page` and `Form`. `Page`'s type is a stateless component (Presentational) and `Form`'s type should be a stateful component.

`Page` works fine, however, the compiler gives me an error two places and I'm not sure what is the proper typing. Please read the comments below.

```
interface ConfigProps {
  // ...
}

interface ConfigState {
 // ...
}

interface TemplateConfiguration<T> {

  Form: React.Component<ConfigProps, ConfigState>;
  Page: React.FunctionComponent<T>; // this one works here

}

const myConfig: TemplateConfiguration  = {
  Page: ({arg1, arg2}) => (<div>...</div>), // and works here
  Form: class extends React.Component<ConfigProps, ConfigState> {
      // ^^^^ --- Type 'typeof Form' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<ConfigProps, ConfigState, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more

    render() {
      return (<div>Some text here</div>);
    }
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { Form, Page } = myConfig;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form  /> // JSX element type 'Form' does not have any construct or call signatures
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using just `ComponentType<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`React.ComponentClass`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L479) instead of `React.Component`

```
Form: React.Component<ConfigProps, ConfigState>;
```

should be

```
Form: React.ComponentClass<ConfigProps, ConfigState>;
```